# Discard child repo from parent repo in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github

I am trying to pull code from the xcode. I am currently on parent repo and there is another child repo inside parent repo. When I am trying to pull it with source control - > pull, its showing an alert message.

> "Commit or discard the changes and try again."

I tried to discard many times, but it doesn't allow me to pull.